# mysql order by str_to_date doesn't work

Tags: mysql

i have a table with date(actually they are string time in this format: 2004-Mar). I want to rank the record based on this date, so i have the following query:

```
SELECT *,STR_TO_DATE(detail,'%Y-%b') 
FROM table2 JOIN user_table 
ON table2.user_id = user_table.id 
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(detail,'%Y-%b') DESC 
WHERE table2_col = 11;
```

But this query doesn't work, it asks me to check syntax err near 'WHERE table2_col = 11' at line 5

If i delete ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(detail,'%Y-%b') DESC , then everything works fine. so i think the error comes from str_to_date? what's wrong with my code? 
thanks

Comment: `WHERE` statements need to go before `ORDER BY` statements (Your syntax error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order by should come after the where clause

Try this::

```
SELECT *,STR_TO_DATE(detail,'%Y-%b') 
FROM table2 JOIN user_table 
ON table2.user_id = user_table.id 

WHERE table2_col = 11
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(detail,'%Y-%b') DESC 
;
```